# Expected false to be true when test react component with jasmine jsdom and enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine, jsdom, enzyme

When I ran the jasmine as a gulp task, the test seems runs well, though first one is always considered failed. I am not sure where the problem is.

React Component

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

const propTypes = {};

const defaultProps = {};

class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="foo"> </div>
    );
  }
}

Foo.propTypes = propTypes;
Foo.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default Foo;
```

Spec File

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Foo from './foo.react';
import jsDom from 'jsdom';

global.document = jsDom.jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};


describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    console.log(shallow(<Foo />));
    expect(shallow(<Foo />).contains(<div className="foo" />)).toBe(true);//.toBe(true)
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(shallow(<Foo />).is('.foo')).toBe(true);
  });

  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(mount(<Foo />).find('.foo').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found out I have to change my return to 
`<div className="foo" />` instead of `<div className="foo"> </div>`

Then the test will pass.

Do not yet understand why they are different still though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue may be in the white space you have in `<div className="foo"> </div>`

`contains` checks for an exact match, and an empty tag is different than the same tag containing a space characters. See also this discussion for a possible workaround involving `elem.html()`